# Generate Random String as String, not List

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits
import string
import random


def generatestr():
    str0 = random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,2) + random.sample(ascii_uppercase,1) + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,2)
    str1 = random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,5)
    str2 = random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,3) + random.sample(ascii_uppercase,1) + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,1)
    str3 = random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,5)
    str4 = random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,4)
    key = str(str0) + "-" + str(str1) + "-" + str(str2) + "-" + str(str3) + "-" + str(str4) + "Z"
    return ''.join(key)

    

print(generatestr())
```

['H', 'J', 'U', 'V', '8']-['6', '4', '5', 'Z', '0']-['L', '8', '7', 'D', 'Q']-['9', 'P', 'F', 'T', 'B']-['M', '8', 'G', 'V']Z

Expected output: ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDZ

Comment: Why don't you `''.join` `str0` instead of `key`?

Comment: `random.sample` returns a list which you would need to join in order to get a string.

Comment: @JohnColeman What do you mean exactly? Apologies as this is a new topic for me

Comment: `random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,2)` is a list of 2 characters but `''.join(random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,2))` would be a string of length 2 -- which is what you want.

Comment: `return '-'.join(map("".join, (str0, str1, str2, str3, str4))`

Answer (score 1):

Random.sample returns a list. When you use str(str0) then you change a list to a string which outputs: ['H', 'J', 'U', 'V', '8']

In order to get expected output, you have to change a line to:

```
key = "".join(str0) + "-" + "".join(str1) + "-" + "".join(str2) + "-" + "".join(str3) + "-" + "".join(str4) + "Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    key = ''.join(str0) + "-" + ''.join(str1) + "-" + ''.join(str2) + "-" + ''.join(str3) + "-" + ''.join(str4) + "Z"
    return key
```

Comment: This answer is exactly identical to an earlier answer by @Jodla. StackOverflow considers this a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`str` when used on a collection typically gives a string that looks like an inline representation of the collection, hence

```
str([1,2,3])
```

outputs

```
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

To give a string representation of a list the way you want it, you want to join the items of the list. `my_string.join`, as you've already noticed, applies the `str` function to each item of a list, concatenates all the results, separating them using the value of the string `my_string`, then returns the result. Hence

```
''.join([1,2,3])
```

outputs

```
'123'
```

So this is what you want:

```
def generatestr():
    rands = []
    rands.append(random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,2) + random.sample(ascii_uppercase,1) + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,2))
    rands.append(random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,5))
    rands.append(random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,3) + random.sample(ascii_uppercase,1) + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,1))
    rands.append(random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,5))
    rands.append(random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase,4))
    return '-'.join([''.join(rand_list) for rand_list in rands])
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have said it: `random.sample()` returns a list. My approach is to generate a big list, then join together using an empty string:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits
import random


def generatestr():
    key = (
        random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 2)
        + random.sample(ascii_uppercase, 1)
        + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 2)
        + ["-"]
        + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 5)
        + ["-"]
        + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 3)
        + random.sample(ascii_uppercase, 1)
        + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 1)
        + ["-"]
        + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 5)
        + random.sample(digits + ascii_uppercase, 4)
    )
    return "".join(key)


print(generatestr())
```

## Notes

- Do no need to `import string`
- This solution uses `black` to format the code for reaability

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string
random_string1 = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k =5))
random_string2 = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k =5))
random_string3 = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k =3))
random_string4 = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k =2))
print(random_string1+"-"+random_string2+"-"+random_string3+"-"+random_string4)
```

**Output:-**

> ZZUSR-ZUNVA-CFS-HE